# PowerShell exit code when run from VBScript

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I am simply trying to get a success or failure code out of a PowerShell script when run via VBScript with `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run(strCMD, 0, True)`.

I thought `Exit` produced an exit code, but when I end my PS script with `Exit 9` the value returned to the VBScript above is still `0`.

The VBScript is:

```
strCmd = "powershell.exe -noLogo -executionpolicy bypass -file ""\\Mac\Px\Support\Px Tools\Dev 3.3.#\_Spikes\TestMessage.ps1"" -message:""I'm ALIVE"""
result = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run(strCMD, 0, True)
msgBox result
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Return "Your Value"` in your ps script instead of `Exit`

Take care powershell will return anything what will be printed to the console

Comment: guiwhatsthat, I have no tried Exit, Return and Write-Host. None of which seem to work with VBScript's .Run method. Are these actually working for you? FWIW, I am using PS 2.0, because I must. I guess I need to spin up a Windows 10 VM and test this in current PS. Maybe it's juts a bug in PS 2.0.

Comment: I made a quick example with powershell. I got a returnvalue with return and with exit i did not got one. Note Return will no end your script

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Set wso=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
rc=wso.Run(strCMD, 0, True)
MsgBox "returncode=" & rc
```

Comment: That's basically what I am doing. My my variables are different, and I am inlining the CreateObject, but it's the same functionality. I updated the OP to show the actual code.

Comment: Tested with simplest .ps1 (`exit 9`) and it works. What's in your .ps1?

Comment: I have tested with just Exit 9 also. Still no joy, the only thing getting returned is 0.
BTW, how are you getting the Code formatting in comments? ;)

Comment: Oh, wait a minute. I had a blank line before that Exit. With literally one line, it works. As soon as I introduce any non comment code it stops working. But that gives me something to start from. I can start adding bits of my required code till it breaks.

Comment: Finally found it. I had reused the main PS code from a utility I already had written, and I had [CmdletBinding()] in there. No need in a script rather than a function, and it seems it causes all sorts of other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just write

```
exit 123
```

in TestMessage.ps1